# How to make transparent corners of borders for a perspective effect?

Tags: css, transparency

As I'm making a new design for an existing website, I have to draw some elements in "perspective".

By using some `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, it was easy to make it, but the corners added are in a fixed color (white) wich is ok with the background (white) but not with some other elements (pictures, other bg color blocks). Unfortunatly [`:outside`, `:before(2)` and  `:after(2)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#nesting) doesn't seem to work.

[image: Demo of the white corners]

So how could I make the following menu in `CSS` with transparent corners (without gif, png or adding some `span`) ?

**[> Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MuSP/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="relief">Some content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.relief {
position:relative;
border-left:10px solid #CCC;
border-bottom:10px solid #CCC;
border-right:1px solid #CCC;
border-top:1px solid #CCC;
padding:10px;
background:#EDEDED;}

.relief:before, .relief:after {
content:"";
border:10px solid transparent;
position:absolute;
display:block;
z-index:10;}

.relief:before {
left:-10px;
top:-10px;
border-left:10px solid #FFF;
border-top:10px solid #FFF;}

.relief:after {
right:-10px;bottom:-10px;
border-right:10px solid #FFF;
border-bottom:10px solid #FFF;}
```

The best I made for it with another system, made a bottom-left transparent corner and a top-left white border, that I don't want to be displayed : **[2nd fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MuSP/4/)**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I misundestood. I'm sorry @Valky.

Comment: Don't worry, I've changed the title of my question to "transparent corners of borders", it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be done with just plain CSS. Be sure to add any vendor prefixes.

```
div {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -2px 2px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -3px 3px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -4px 4px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -5px 5px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8zcW/

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I've tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/Z8zcW/1/ works fine. +1

Comment: But it seems that it doesn't work on mobiles. Tested with an iPhone 3.

Comment: To support older mobiles, try adding vendor prefixes. `-webkit-` in the case of iPhones.